# SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 41584

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, http-request

Estou fazendo um app em flutter e testando em um dispositivo real pelo USB. O app consome uma API em NodeJS que roda localmente e ao tentar fazer uma requisição do tipo POST eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
E/flutter (16640): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 41620
E/flutter (16640): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:677:35)
E/flutter (16640): #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1680:26)
E/flutter (16640): #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
E/flutter (16640): #3      Socket._startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1891:22)
E/flutter (16640): #4      Socket.startConnect (dart:io/socket.dart:738:21)
E/flutter (16640): #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2439:18)
E/flutter (16640): #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2805:12)
E/flutter (16640): #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2810:12)
E/flutter (16640): #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2694:12)
E/flutter (16640): #9      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2568:7)
E/flutter (16640): #10     IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:30:38)
E/flutter (16640): #11     BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:38)
E/flutter (16640): #12     BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (16640): #13     post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
E/flutter (16640): #14     _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
E/flutter (16640): #15     post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
E/flutter (16640): #16     LoginPage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:quifer/pages/loginpage.dart:277:29)
E/flutter (16640): #17     LoginPage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:quifer/pages/loginpage.dart:262:36)
E/flutter (16640): #18     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter (16640): #19     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
E/flutter (16640): #20     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
E/flutter (16640): #21     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter (16640): #22     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
E/flutter (16640): #23     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (16640): #24     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:444:20)
E/flutter (16640): #25     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
E/flutter (16640): #26     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
E/flutter (16640): #27     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter (16640): #28     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter (16640): #29     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter (16640): #30     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter (16640): #31     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter (16640): #32     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (16640): #33     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (16640): #34     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
E/flutter (16640): #35     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
E/flutter (16640): #36     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
E/flutter (16640):
```

O que estou tentando fazer (a API roda em localhost mas para acessar pelo dispositivo físico tem que ser passado 10.0.2.2):

```
SizedBox(
    width: 350,
    height: 55,
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {

        // Se os TextFields não forem vazios
        if (_passController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            _userController.text.isNotEmpty) {

          // Cria um mapa para ser convertido para json na hora da request
          Map c = {
            "email": "${_userController.text}",
            "password": "${_passController.text}",
          };

          // AQUI ACONTECE A REQUISIÇÃO
          http.post(
            Uri.parse(
              "http://10.0.2.2:8888/api/users/__/auth/",
            ),
            body: json.encode(c),
          )
          .then((response) {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              // Credentials().saveCredentials(c).then((value) => null);
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home"); // redireciona para a home
            } else {
              print(response.body); // DESCOMENTE PARA DEBUG
              // codigo extra
            }
          });
        }
      },
      child: Text("Enviar"),
    ),
  );
```

Não acho que seja necesário o código do servidor visto que o mesmo está funcionando no navegador, no Postman e no ThunderClient. Apenas no app que eu obtenho este erro.

Saída do comando flutter doctor:

```
❯ flutter doctor                    
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-37-generic, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe se a Wifi do dispositivo que vocês esta utilizando para depurar via USB esta ligada e conectada na mesma rede Wifi do pc que vocês esta programando. Tive o mesmo problema e foi resolvido desta maneira.